# ggplot2 - geom_tile border rendering

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm looking to render 2 grids with different cell border length, to illustrate how to deal with differences in how much cells overlap (aggregating data).

Consider the following ggplot2 plot:

[image: Two rasters plot]

Made with the following code:

```
library("ggplot2")
library("gtools")

big_cell_size = 1
small_cell_size = 0.3
width = 4

make_cell_data <- function(cell_size) {
  n_cells = width / cell_size
  vals = seq(from = cell_size / 2, to = width, by = cell_size)
  perms <- permutations(length(vals),2, v=vals)
  x_vals <- append(perms[,1], vals)
  y_vals <- append(perms[,2], vals)
  data.frame(x = x_vals, y = y_vals)
}

p <- ggplot(data = make_cell_data(big_cell_size), aes(x, y))
p <- p + labs(x="", y="")

p <- p + geom_tile(data = make_cell_data(big_cell_size), alpha=0, color="black", width=1, height=1)
p <- p + geom_tile(data = make_cell_data(small_cell_size), alpha=0, color="darkorange", width=0.3, height=0.3, linetype="35")

p <- p + theme(aspect.ratio=1)
p
```

I'm using geom_tile because when using geom_raster, there doesn't seem to be a way to make cells transparent.

My questions:

- Is it possible to set an alpha on geom_raster?
- I used a dotted line for the orange grid, because some lines from the two grids overlap and I wanted a way to show 'both' at the same time. However as you can see, all cells that are not on the outer border of the orange grid have irregular patterns. That is because each tile is rendered without considering if there was already a line there; so lines are rendered twice with the pattern slightly offset. Is there a way to fix this?
- The whole reason I used dotted lines is because I can't find a way to make a line (border) thicker than 1 pixel. Is there a way to render lines with a certain width?
- Are there other visual design patterns to solve the problem of overlapping lines between regularly occurring geometries?
- Is there a neater way to generate a matrix with all permutations of a vector of number, that includes 'self-permutations'? gtools.permutations doesn't include those so now what I thought should be a one-liner is 5 lines.

Comment: what is a self-permutation?

Comment: Sorry I don't know the right term - what I mean is, given c(1,2), the result should have not only (1,2) and (2,1) but also (1,1) and (2,2).

Answer (score 0):

You have many questions wrapped up in one, so it might be better to break them up in different questions. In terms of wanting to make the different groups of your number, here are two methods from `gtools` that should achieve what you want.

```
gtools::combinations(3,2,letters[1:3],repeats=TRUE)
```

yields

```
     [,1] [,2]
[1,] "a"  "a" 
[2,] "a"  "b" 
[3,] "a"  "c" 
[4,] "b"  "b" 
[5,] "b"  "c" 
[6,] "c"  "c"

gtools::permutations(3,2,letters[1:3],repeats=TRUE)
```

yields

```
[,1] [,2]
 [1,] "a"  "a" 
 [2,] "a"  "b" 
 [3,] "a"  "c" 
 [4,] "b"  "a" 
 [5,] "b"  "b" 
 [6,] "b"  "c" 
 [7,] "c"  "a" 
 [8,] "c"  "b" 
 [9,] "c"  "c"
```

Comment: Thank you, I had misunderstood the repeats parameter. Re: the multiple questions - since the first couple are really different angles on the same underlying issue, I figured I wouldn't question-spam 4 different similar-but-slightly-different ones. The last one was more an afterthought as I was typing. But yeah, you're right.